# Is there any way to set a default status for Entries, either globally or per Section?

Tags: entries, sections, workflow

The subject more or less covers it — is there any way to set the default status for Entries, either on a Section by Section basis, or globally?

I have a client that doesn't want to accidentally set something live when they save something without deliberately setting it to published.

At the moment it looks like I have two options:

- Create an un-Crafty "Publish" checkbox field that I check for in my templates.
- Use User Groups to keep some users from publishing — this is a little overkill for them, though. They don't want to keep these people from publishing, just try to limit people publishing content without meaning to.

Comment: As far as I know, you just coined *un-Crafty* here. And I like it.

Comment: This is a great question. It might be a functionality request. Similarly, I recently had a desire to make a post expiration date a required field. Would be nice to be able to control some of these items per section/entry type.

Comment: Feature requested : http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9328431-configure-new-entry-default-status-to-draft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two options are the only ones thus far. If you would like this feature you can leave a post on the [G+ group](https://plus.google.com/communities/106505340287442511226), or email them at: support@buildwithcraft.com

Answer (score 2):

As of Craft 2.6.2771, sections now have a “Default Entry Status” section.